# How to cut hairs in two pieces in blender?

Tags: hair

I'm wondering how to animate a scissor to cut Long hair in two pieces and the second fold down.

Comment: Be sure to follow "Replace object with another on collision" topic for any clues if someone comments or answers: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/221211/replace-object-with-another-on-collision